# problema con tipo de dato void c++

Tags: c++, punteros, matriz

Buenas a todos resulta que estaba programando algoritmos de ordenamiento en C++ pero al momento de desear comparar resulta que no se cómo hacerlo
tengo entendido que en C++ existe la función `is_same` para comparar tipos de datos pero mi pregunta es como comparo un tipo de dato `void` con un `char` sabiendo que el tipo de dato `void` es doble puntero para una matriz.

Tengo este código dónde resaltó la línea es donde no se que rollo alguien me puede explicar:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio_ext.h>
#include <string>
#include<chrono>
void agregar_elementos(int tipo,int nElem,int almc,void **matrizM,void *arrayM);
void utilizar_ordenamientos(){
    int nElem=0;
    int almc=0;
    char tipo;
    cout << "\n Dame el numero de datos a ordenar";
    cin >> nElem;
    cout<< "\n B = Ordenamiento Burbuja";
    cout<< "\n T = Ordenamiento Intercalacion";
    cout<< "\n S = Ordenamiento Seleccion";
    cout<< "\n I = ordenamientos Insercion";
    cout<< "\n R = Ordenamiento Radix";
    cout<< "\n Q = Ordenamiento Quicksort";
    cout << "\n ELIGE EL TIPO DE ORDENAMIENTO";
    cin>> tipo;
    cout << "\n 1.-ALMACENAMIENTO PARA MATRIZ";
    cout << "\n 2.-ALMACENAMIENTO PARA ARRAY";
    cout <<"\1 ELIGE EL TIPO DE ALMACENAMIENTO";
    cin >> almc;
    void **matrizM=NULL,*arrayM=NULL;
    if (almc==1){
        matrizM=(void **)malloc(sizeof(void **)*nElem);
        agregar_elementos(tipo,nElem,almc,&matrizM[0],NULL);
    }else{
        agregar_elementos(tipo,nElem,almc,NULL,arrayM);
    }
}

void agregar_elementos(int tipo,int nElem,int almc,void **matrizM,void *arrayM){
        Ordenamientos *ordX;
    using DType = std::chrono::microseconds;
    char **matrizM_c,*arrayM_c;
    for (int index = 0; index < nElem; index++)
    {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            if (almc==1){
                cout<<"INGRESA EL ELEMENTO -->"<<x<<"posicion matriz ["<<index<<"}"<<"{"<<x<<"}--->";
                matrizM[x]=(void *)malloc(sizeof(void *)*5);
                scanf("%p",&matrizM[index]+x);
                

            }else{
                cout<<"INGRESA EL ELEMENTO -->"<<x<<"posicion array"<<"{"<<x<<"}--->";
                scanf("%p",&arrayM+x);
            }
        if(is_same<typeof(matrizM[index]+x),char>::value)
        {
            printf("\n?????????");
        }
            if(std::is_same<typeof(matrizM[index]+x),char>::value){
                cout<<"La matriz es de tipo char";
                //matrizM_c[X]=(char **) matrizM;
                ordX=new Ordenamientos(tipo,matrizM_c,nElem);
            }else
                if (is_same<typeof(matrizM),int** >::value){        
        
            }
            
            __fpurge(stdin);

        }
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    ordX->agregarElementosM();
}
int main()
{
    utilizar_ordenamientos();

    return 0;
}
```

en la parte de la sentencia if de la funcion agregar elementos como se supone que debo de comparar el tipo de dato void** matrizM con por ejemplo un tipo de dato char o int

Comment: Coloca tu codigo, no una imagen, para que así la comunidad pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tengo entendido que en C++ existe la función `is_same` para comparar tipos de datos

[`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) ni siquiera es una función, es una estructura plantilla que recibe dos tipos como parámetros de plantilla y en el caso de que ambos parámetros sean el mismo tipo el miembro `value` tendrá valor `true`. Así que no sirve para comparar **valores**, que es lo que parece que quieres comparar.

> como comparo un tipo de dato `void`

Los tipos de datos no son comparables, lo que quieres comparar son **valores**, y no puedes comparar un valor `void` con nada ya que `void` es literalmente un tipo vacío (*void* significa vacío en inglés) y ni siquiera es instanciable.

> como comparo un tipo de dato `void` con un `char` sabiendo que el tipo de dato `void` es doble puntero para una matriz.

No lo haces, los tipos son incompatibles. Un puntero a `void` es un apuntador genérico que carece de tipo subyacente; es lo más parecido a memoria en crudo que puedes manejar en C++. Si tienes una matriz a datos tipados (datos con tipo, al contrario que un puntero a `void` que carece de información de tipo) compara los **elementos** de dicha matriz:

```
char valor;
char matriz[N];

if (matriz[0] == valor) // comparación
{
}
```

Si lo que quieres hacer es comparar valores de tipos arbitrarios debes usar plantillas, no punteros a `void`.

Si lo que quieres es:

> Saber si el dato de la matriz que estoy introduciendo es de tipo Char o int ya sea usando templates o punteros o alguna librería alguna idea

Puedes hacer una función que compruebe si una formación de datos es `char` o `int`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ELEMENTOS>
bool matriz_de_caracteres(const T (&)[ELEMENTOS])
{
    return std::is_same<T, char>::value;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t ELEMENTOS>
bool matriz_de_enteros(const T (&)[ELEMENTOS])
{
    return std::is_same<T, int>::value;
}

int main()
{
    int matriz_de_int[100]{};
    char matriz_de_char[100]{};
    float matriz_de_float[100]{};

    std::cout
        << "Es de char? " << matriz_de_caracteres(matriz_de_int) << '\n'
        << "Es de char? " << matriz_de_caracteres(matriz_de_char) << '\n'
        << "Es de char? " << matriz_de_caracteres(matriz_de_float) << '\n'
        << "Es de int? " << matriz_de_enteros(matriz_de_int) << '\n'
        << "Es de int? " << matriz_de_enteros(matriz_de_char) << '\n'
        << "Es de int? " << matriz_de_enteros(matriz_de_float) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##pVJNa8MwDD3Hv8J0sCawQXZNQ3bKbR@H5daV4DneZnDsYCuDtfS3Z3L6GdpBaH17kt7Tk2TeNPdcMf3VdTdSc9VWgqbSOLCC1Rk5xOC3ESVYJsFlhICoG8VgG9esFrS4ow6qJHFyiYU0f8qf85fi9S0jH8YoWjOwcllWouTMMg7CChdyox3Qgoa30XxPWERkRSg@K6C1eqMqXemwS4pd@DezWZL8MNWKGVlfZ0ZodGIudCI1DIwgRmmpQ88LNmjXCNH8IY4Xq/WMBH6E440gPCQ/lWHHzB7v0yToXXDTAgmCNKWT3FE8kNd4pBOKkbOrHjiJfNn0XU8vlPCV12r0Y50XQYcnGrtDjZhjHP3/Gcbxh/79Yba/JMa/0HV/):

> ```
> Es de char? 0
> Es de char? 1
> Es de char? 0
> Es de int? 1
> Es de int? 0
> Es de int? 0
> ```

Comment: Oye y co.o se supone que hago e entonces lo que me estás mencionando de comparar valore de tipos arbitrarios usando plantillas alguna idea ?

Comment: Si sólo quieres comparar es una cosa, si quieres hacer algo diferente es otra ¿qué quieres hacer en concreto?

Comment: Saber si el dato de la matriz  que estoy introduciendo es de tipo Char o int ya sea usando templates o punteros o alguna librería alguna idea ?

Comment: Gracias hermano te seguiré me funcionó eres un Dios en esto gracias te seguiré en esta comunidad